# Problem with uploading images in production via Cloudinary C# running on .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, cloudinary

I have a problem using Cloudinary in production, the code I will paste below works locally but fails in production.

Local using VS2019 no error is shown, in production on a subdomain via https this error occurs.

The controller is as follows:

```
using CloudinaryDotNet;
using CloudinaryDotNet.Actions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SGVCatalogBE.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SGVCatalogBE.Controllers
{
    public class ProvaController:BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly IPhotoService _photoService;

        public ProvaController(IPhotoService photoService)
        {
            _photoService = photoService;
        }

        [HttpPost("add-photo")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ImageUploadResult>> AddPhoto(IFormFile file)
        {
            Account account = new Account("xxxxxx",
                                          "123456789",
                                          "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
            cloudinary.Api.Secure = true;

            var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();

                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
                {
                    File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, stream),
                    Transformation = new Transformation().Height(500).Width(500).Crop("fill").Gravity("face")
                };

                try
                {
                    cloudinary.Api.Secure = true;
                    uploadResult = await cloudinary.UploadAsync(uploadParams);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500, ex);
                }                
            }

            return uploadResult;
        }
    }
}
```

The error returned is:

```
{
    "statusCode": null,
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at CloudinaryDotNet.ApiShared.CallAsync(HttpMethod method, String url, SortedDictionary`2 parameters, FileDescription file, Dictionary`2 extraHeaders, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)\r\n   at CloudinaryDotNet.ApiShared.CallAndParseAsync[T](HttpMethod method, String url, SortedDictionary`2 parameters, FileDescription file, Dictionary`2 extraHeaders, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)\r\n   at SGVCatalogBE.Controllers.ProvaController.AddPhoto(IFormFile file) in C:\\Users\\Domenico\\Desktop\\SGVCatalog\\SGVCatalogBE\\Controllers\\ProvaController.cs:line 48",
    "message": "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.",
    "data": {},
    "innerException": {
        "ClassName": "System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException",
        "Message": "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch",
        "Data": null,
        "InnerException": null,
        "HelpURL": null,
        "StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)",
        "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
        "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
        "ExceptionMethod": null,
        "HResult": -2146233087,
        "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
        "WatsonBuckets": null
    },
    "helpLink": null,
    "source": "System.Net.Http",
    "hResult": -2146233087
}
```

The API is deployed on a server with IIS.

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: This error usually means that your serverdoes not trust Cloudinary certificate. However since Cloudinary is signed by trusted Root CA, this likely means somehow machine that runs this app doesn't have the latest set of Root CA. You may need to consult with your IT on this.
Or, it could be as well that you have a MITM/proxy in between that intercept the HTTPS traffic, so the certificate that your app received is from MITM instead from Cloudinary, hence the mismatch hostname: `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I called the IT manager who found that the web protection system was blocking calls to api.cloudinary.com, we solved the problem. Thank you very much.